# Authorization failing using Spring Boot and Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm using authorization of OAUTH2 using Spring Security and Spring boot

Getting this error while trying to build and run the spring application :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.security.oauth2.client-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientProperties': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client id must not be empty.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:678) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at com.project.springboot.Application.main(Application.java:11) ~[main/:na]
```

My OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig looks like the following:

```
package com.project.springboot.config.auth;

import com.project.springboot.domain.user.Role;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/h2-console/**", "/profile").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole(Role.USER.name())
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                        .userInfoEndpoint()
                            .userService(customOAuth2UserService);
    }
}
```

and this is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group 'com.hkh.project'
version '1.0.4-SNAPSHOT-'+new Date().format("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache')
    compile('com.h2database:h2')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client')
    compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc')

    compile("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client")

    testCompile "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testAnnotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

what could be the possible solution for this error

it is unable to run the application

Comment: How does your CustomOAuth2UserService look like?

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be related to wrong dependency configuration.

If you are going to configure your Application to handle OAuth2 based authentication,
you need `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security` and  `org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2` dependencies.

There is no strictly need of `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`.

Answer (score 1):

dependency:
compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'

In your SecurityConfig class include @EnableOAuth2Sso

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
http
.csrf().disable()
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/...").permitAll()
.and().httpBasic();
}

In your property specify client.accessTokenUri,client.userAuthorizationUri,client.scope,client.clientId,client.clientSecreat,resource.userInfoUri

Controller:
create a public method  and annotate with @ResponseBody that will return Principal

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work by adding to application.yml

```
  authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
```

application.yml:

```
 security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          custom-client:
            client-id: myclientID
            client-secret: <Some Hash Code>
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials

        provider:
           custom-client:
             authorization-uri: https://your-subdomain/oauth2/auth
             token-uri: https://your-subdomain/oauth2/token
             user-info-uri: https://your-subdomain/userinfo
             user-name-attribute: sub
             jwk-set-uri: https://your-subdomain/oauth2/v1/keys
```